# Metaplex-master on github only has Readme file

Tags: hadoop-yarn, solana, metaplex, candy-machine

I am trying to set up a Solana candy machine. I am using the Hasplips Metaplex-master but it only has one readme file. Its supposed to have a js folder, some .JSON files and more. Can any send me a link to the correct Metaplex-master for the candy machine? I can only find the Metaplex contain a readme file.

When I extracted the files all I found was a read me file. I created a js folder myself and tried to run some yarn commands in the Visual Studio code terminal but I need the other .json files that were supposed to be there to execute the commands.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old guide. The js sdk has been deprecated and removed from that repo for months now.
It is way easier to create a candy machine with sugar, e.g. following this guide https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/how-to-guides/my-first-candy-machine-part1